# Octave Forge packages

Tags: windows, octave

I'm running the Window's port of Octave on Windows 10.

I have installed 3 packages; Control, Signal and Communications.

I am wondering if there is a procedure to run to update the Help on disk?

Or should I just use the online help at [Octave Forge online documentation](http://octave.sourceforge.net/functions_by_package.php)

T.I.A.

Comment: If you mean, e.g. `help medfilt1`, then you need to `pkg load signal` first otherwise the help isn't accessible when the function isn't accessible. If you mean "documentation", as in the documentation tab next to the console and editor tabs, then no, I don't think packages install any documentation, so yes, check this online.
However, it might be easier to go straight to the package page for the function references, rather than the general index, e.g. http://octave.sourceforge.net/signal/index.html

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou Ah, yes. I was thinking `help` rather than `doc`.

Comment: Thanks Tasos, yes, I did mean 'Docs'.

Comment: The command to update the packages: `pkg update` also updates the "Help on disk" for packages

Comment: @Andy do packages actually install html documentation separate to their `help` headers then? I wasn't aware of that (nor can I find any such documentation on my installation). I have a feeling you're just referring to the `help` headers. Having said that, the online "documentation" is literally just an html version of the `help` headers, so I guess the answer to OP's question is "There's no separate documentation, just use the help headers; these are identical to the documentation online and can be updated via the `pkg` command if one has an older version". Maybe this is worth a proper answer.

Comment: @Tasos: Some packages has also a "documentation", see for example the interval package: http://octave.sourceforge.net/interval/package_doc/index.html If you use the phrase "help headers" are you refering to texinfo (which is included in the source)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to give a more rounded answer to the question for future readers.

*Core* Octave documentation comes in two forms:

- A manual, which is available in pdf and html form here: http://www.octave.org/doc
  This is the same document that is displayed in the octave GUI when you click on the "Documentation" tab.
- Help headers. These are defined inside each function, and can be summoned via the `help <functionname>` command.

For *Packages* there is *no* distinct html and "help header" versions. There is only help headers. However, these help headers are also available to read online in slightly nicer-looking html format at the octave forge website, listed under their function reference. If your package installation is up-to-date, then the two should be identical.

You can get some information about the package itself on your terminal (such as a short description and list of functions it provides) by typing `pkg describe -verbose <packagename>`, and you can see a changelog via `news <packagename>`. Again, this is the same information that can be found on octave forge, just formatted in nicer html.

Comment: Relative lack of good, in-depth documentation seems to be one of those ongoing sore points in octave, which comes up often in discussions. Good quality documentation contributions are welcome in theory, but I would agree that "help headers" are not always the most appropriate format for documentation. Perhaps it'd be worth having "proper" documentation online and redirect to that from the interpreter ...

Comment: what is missing in your eye? Each function is documented using texinfo. This is used for the function documentation which can be showed with `help` and is used to generate the html pages. Some packages also have a "package documentation", see http://octave.sourceforge.net/interval/package_doc/index.html And there are wiki pages which can be edited by users. Some examples: http://wiki.octave.org/IO_package http://wiki.octave.org/Image_acquisition_package http://wiki.octave.org/Instrument_control_package

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean to sound like I was complaining (or worse, "trolling"). I just know that the quality of documentation has been discussed in the past; e.g. I remember in a chat in IRC that lack of appropriate documentation was a fairly major theme in last year's octconf (though I think that was more aimed at code documentation). In general, the wiki is a bit hit-and-miss, it's not promoted as a main resource (nor do I think it should be). The interval package is a notable exception, and even then its documentation does not feature within the octave client. (cont.)

Comment: And, generally, I've found that help headers contain the bare minimum of information, and if you want more info you''d usually have better luck looking at the matlab documentation for that function (in cases where there's a matlab equivalent). Again, not criticism, I'm well aware of the development constraints and limitations that come with such a massive open-source project. But it's there as an issue.

Comment: @Andy My personal opinion is that there's a reasonably large userbase which could be tempted to contribute towards the documentation side of things if the process was somewhat simpler and more straightforward from the process of contributing to the main codebase itself, and this was visibly encouraged. As it is, the project gives the impression that it's a very 'closed' project (in terms of a tightly knit team, not in terms of licence). I.e, it feels a bit more like a "take it or leave it" deal rather than a community. The fact that the agora website is still dormant is kinda a sign of that.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that it looks like the maintainers doesn't encourage users enough to contribute documentation. And as far as I know there's nobody who wants to work on agora atm. Please share your ideas (and manpower) how Octave can make it easier for the users to contribute. I guess you know about the wiki, the patchtracker and the maintainers list. Perhaps we can move this discussion to the help mailinglist?

Comment: @Andy yes, sorry, I digressed and this isn't the place for such a chat. I don't know if it's worth starting a "thread" on the mailinglist per se, I feel like this would offend more than it would inspire; and like I said, I'm not complaining. I'm very appreciative of all the good (+free!) work octave devs have put in so far. Just my impression of the kind of image the project seems to project outwards. I'm on #octave reasonably often (as `poacheR` --- less so these days, finishing off a thesis), and generally enjoy conversations there; next time you catch me there I'd be happy to have a chat :)